# Restrict access to SQL SERVER 2005 or 2008 Express database to my c# app

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I've always found answers here without having to open a thread, but this time I really need advice from specialists.

My Windows Software creates a SQL Server Express Database as it installs, using scripts, and a IIS Server providing data to users through an extranet web-application.

Database engine can be SQL Server 2005 Express or 2008 Express.

My problematic is the following : I want to restrict access to the database to my IIS server, but I can't use a specific Windows account authentication. I actually use the default windows profile but it's of course not a good solution.

I can't use TDE because of eventuality of 2005 database. I don't want to use CDE because of Indexing loose and performance issues.

I of course can't specify database parameters manually.

Is there a way to create schema or SQL Server user from my c# app, and makes my code the only accessor (except local administrators of the computer of course) to my database ?

What my possibilities are? Which one do would you suggest me?

Comment: have you considered using Sql Server 2012's localDB, or an embedded version of SQL server ( sql server CE for example ). An embedded DB will take the guess work out of which engine is being used and by default will keep the owner to your application.

Comment: It isn't really clear what your problem is: no application can connect to SQL Server without a valid login. So who are the other users or applications that you want to prevent from accessing your database? If someone shouldn't connect, don't give them a login.